# Switching layouts with Caps Lock doesn't work if Caps Lock was pressed right after another key

Tags: keyboard, big-sur, caps-lock

I'm on macOS Big Sur 11.2.1 and I'm experiencing a weird behavior of Caps Lock as the layout switcher.

Caps Lock can be used for switching layouts by turning the `Use Caps Lock key to switch layout` setting in `Settings > Keyboard`.

It's working fine, except when Caps Lock is pressed **right after** another key, e.g. `Backspace`.

Is the issue reproducible for someone else? Is it the macOS issue or the issue of my setup? If it's the macOS issue, could it be fixed somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: What are the two keyboards you are switching between?

Comment: "British - PC" and "Russian - PC"